# auto order in a select

Tags: sql, select

I have a procedure that return daily report between a time example (CreateDate BETWEEN '2012/1/21' AND '2012/2/19')

I want this result

```
1/21
1/22
1/23
.
2/1
.
.
```

But the output is sorted automatically based on the day!!As follows:

```
2/1
2/2
.
2/15
1/21
1/22
1/23
.
.
```

I cant using order by (createdate) because I have this select:

```
SELECT     COUNT(UserId) AS c, DAY(CreateDate) AS d
FROM       dbo.aspnet_Membership
WHERE     (CreateDate BETWEEN '2012/1/21' AND '2012/2/19')
GROUP BY DAY(CreateDate)
```

Comment: If the first column (before the /) is month, you *don't* have that output for that query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to sort by month and day, then you need month of course.

And you *always* need an ORDER BY to guarantee the result order.

```
SELECT     COUNT(UserId) AS c, MONTH(CreateDate) AS m, DAY(CreateDate) AS d
FROM       dbo.aspnet_Membership
WHERE     (CreateDate BETWEEN '2012/1/21' AND '2012/2/19')
GROUP BY  MONTH(CreateDate) AS m, DAY(CreateDate) AS d
ORDER BY  MONTH(CreateDate) AS m, DAY(CreateDate) AS d
```

In this case, the order you got was coincidence because of the GROUP BY (which implies an ORDER BY in MySQL, but not other RDBMS)

Answer (score 1):

If you meant you want to ORDER by day,

this might work for you

```
SELECT  COUNT(UserId) AS c, DAY(CreateDate) AS d 
  FROM    dbo.aspnet_Membership 
WHERE   (CreateDate BETWEEN '2012/1/1' AND '2012/2/29')
  GROUP BY DAY(CreateDate) 
ORDER By d ASC
```

Comment: CreateDate BETWEEN '2012/1/21' AND '2012/2/19' is important!